# The element type 'QrImage' can't be assigned to the list type 'Widget'

Tags: ios

```
class QrConfirmationScreen extends StatelessWidget {
  final String qrData;

  QrConfirmationScreen({required this.qrData});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      backgroundColor: Color(0xFFEA7070),
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text('QR Confirmation'),
        backgroundColor: Color(0xFFEA7070),
      ),
      body: Center(
        child: Column(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
          crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
          children: [
            Text(
              'Generated QR Code',
              style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white, fontSize: 20),
            ),
            SizedBox(height: 20),
            if (qrData.isNotEmpty)
              QrImage(
                data: qrData,
                version: QrVersions.auto,
                size: 200.0,
              )
            else
              Text(
                'No QR code to display.',
                style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white, fontSize: 18),
              ),
            SizedBox(height: 20),
            ElevatedButton(
              onPressed: () {
                Navigator.pop(context);
              },
              style: ElevatedButton.styleFrom(
                primary: Colors.white,
                padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 60, vertical: 30),
              ),
              child: Text('Go back to Home', style: TextStyle(color: Color(0xFF000000), fontSize: 24)),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

This is the full code for my Qr code. In this code

```
QrImage(
                data: qrData,
                version: QrVersions.auto,
                size: 200.0,
              )
```

This part keeps giving me the same error as the title.

> The element type 'QrImage' can't be assigned to the list type 'Widget'

I checked the version of the qr_flutter package being used in the 'pubspec.yaml' file and updated it to the latest version. I tried using type conversion 'as Widget' and wrapping it in 'Container' and returning it, but the same error continued and the result did not change.